# 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" error

Tags: sql, oracle

have this error even though table present

```
select count(eventguest.memberid) + x as total, eventid
from (
    select count(eventmember.memberid) as X, eventmember.eventid
    from eventmember
    group by eventid
)
inner join eventguest on eventmember.eventid = eventguest.eventid
group by eventid
```

> ORA-00904: "EVENTMEMBER"."EVENTID": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 16 Column: 15

Comment: This is because eventmember.eventid is not accessible out side of the subquery in from clause. You need to make an alias to the query and use <alias>.eventid.

Comment: This query does not look useful.  I would  suggest that you ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Please don't tag with MySQL if you are using Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query should work correctly:

```
SELECT Count(eventguest.memberid) + x AS total, 
    Y.eventid 
FROM   
(
 SELECT Count(eventmember.memberid) AS X, 
       eventmember.eventid 
 FROM   eventmember 
 GROUP  BY eventid
) Y
INNER JOIN eventguest 
ON Y.eventid = eventguest.eventid 
GROUP  BY Y.eventid
```

Comment: Hi , getting error ORA-00904: "X"."EVENTID": invalid identifier

Comment: It should be Y.EVENTID

Comment: ORA-00904: "EVENTGUEST"."MEMBERID": invalid identifier

Comment: please check if eventguest has memberid field

Comment: yes it has.. and if i select eventguest.memberid from eventguest; it will display result w/o any issue

Comment: in the query you are expecting eventguest.memberid not eventguest.eventid
Please check the query

Comment: Hi , the thing worked..i should have changed eventguest.guestid instead :) silly mistake.. but have an issue.. i designed this query to sum the counts of member id ang guest id and display along with event id .. but the current version only displays only if evenguest and event member member id is same ( i.e , for common events) . any idea how to solve this by editing the script

Comment: What i require is display eventid, show total count (eventguest.guestid) , show total count (eventmember.memberid)

Comment: hi,
Please share the full schema of tables or better ask a new question with the expected result.